# Date format in SQL server mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql-server, date, date-conversion

My date format is 'dd/mm/yyyy' and I want to change it in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format.

I tried below query-

```
Select convert(nvarchar,creation_date,101)
```

but it is still showing old format.

Comment: Do you store `date` values as `nvarchar`?

Comment: Yes.. nvarchar(200)

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. `nvarchar` isn't a date type. Use the correct type, `date`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, `datetime`. Anything else is just trying to cover up a critical bug and simply won't work. Only 5% of people use the US-only date format. No matter who you think your customers/clients are, trying to work with text instead of dates **guarantees conversion errors and serious repercussions**. There's no way to tell if `4/7` is April 7th or July 4th and no way to prevent the storage of invalid values.

Comment: If you think that's an exaggeration, check [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html)

Comment: Why is a text type used instead of a date type in the first place? The inflated bills, missed flights, outrageous fines we see in the news every few months are caused by this particular bug - storing strings instead of dates.

Comment: Honestly, just fix your design; don't store data and time values as a string. If you want to *present* the value in a specific format, that is a job for the presentation layer. Store the data in a [Date and Time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are currently storing your dates as *text* in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, and you want to display them in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, then you need to make a roundtrip from text to date, and back to text again:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, '24/07/2022 12:34:56', 103), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
-- 07/24/2022 12:34:56
```

The first inner call to `CONVERT` generates a bona fide datetime from the input text date.  The second outer call to `FORMAT` generates text output in `mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format.

Comment: Hi.. thanks now I am able to change the format but my date column also has time example.. "01/12/2022 16:12:01" .. is there a way to include time also?

Comment: @NehaGill I have updated my question.  You should be able to use `FORMAT()` to generate the text output you want.

Comment: Dates shouldn't be stored as text in the first place. There's absolutely no benefit but a *lot* of real-life downsides

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I couldn't agree more.  Maybe the OP is stuck with a bad table design.  I answered directly to the question, but your comment is very relevant here.